# Is there a way to join two collections in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Let's say I have an array retrieved from an HTTP request:

```
$request['sports'] => [0 => 'basketball', 1 => 'bowling', 2 => 'Tennis'];
```

And then, in my database I retrieved this collection:

```
$sports = [0 => 'basketball', 1 => 'bowling', 3 => 'boxing']
```

Is there a function in laravel where the "boxing" sport in database will be removed since it is not found on the collection in HTTP request. And the "Tennis" will be added on the database since it is included on the collection in HTTP request. No action for "basketball" and "bowling" since they both found on the request and on the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create collection from array using collect() helper and then filter required elements - that are in one array and not in another. Here is an example:

```
    $request['sports'] = [0 => 'basketball', 1 => 'bowling', 2 => 'Tennis'];
    $db = [0 => 'basketball', 1 => 'bowling', 3 => 'boxing'];

    // create collections
    $requestCollection = collect($request['sports']);
    $dbCollection = collect($db);

    // filter items from db colection, that are not in request collection
    $toDelete = $dbCollection->filter(function ($item) use ($requestCollection) {
        return !$requestCollection->contains($item);
    })->each(function ($item){
        // todo: delete them
    });
    // filter items from request colection, that are not in db collection
    $toAdd = collect($requestCollection)->filter(function ($item) use ($dbCollection) {
        return !$dbCollection->contains($item);
    })->each(function ($item){
        // todo: add them
    });

    dd($toDelete, $toAdd);
```

dd will print out:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1953
  #items: array:1 [
    3 => "boxing"
  ]
}
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1954
  #items: array:1 [
    2 => "Tennis"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = collect(['basketball', 'bowling', 'Tennis']);
$database = collect(['basketball', 'bowling', 'boxing']);

$added = $input->diff($database);
$removed = $database->diff($input);

$database->concat($added)->diff($removed);

// ['basketball', 'bowling', 'Tennis'];
```